# three.js bird animation - Decease flying speed

Tags: javascript, jquery, three.js

I'm using three.js bird animation. I just want to decease birds flying speed. Right now I have all default settings enabled. (Except flying units. I increased to 20 | var i = 0; i < 20; i ++ )

I found a place where we can edit bird speed. ( Don't know that's the right place) 
[Link][1] to that file(Line number: 48)

```
var Boid = function() {
                var vector = new THREE.Vector3(),
                _acceleration, _width = 500, _height = 500, _depth = 200, _goal, _neighborhoodRadius = 100,
                Here _maxSpeed = 4 Here, _maxSteerForce = 0.1, _avoidWalls = false;
                this.position = new THREE.Vector3();
                this.velocity = new THREE.Vector3();
                _acceleration = new THREE.Vector3();
                this.setGoal = function ( target ) {
                    _goal = target;
                };
  [1]:
```

**The problem**

When I edit _maxSpeed = 4 to _maxSpeed = 3, only one bird flock moving around.(All birds stick to one flock) Or rarely just another one or two flocks only.

Any suggestions?

https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/canvas_geometry_birds.html

Comment: Just an idea. On the lines 356-358 (https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/canvas_geometry_birds.html#L356), what happens if to make something like `boid.velocity.x = 0.25 * (Math.random() * 2 - 1)` for each coordinate?

Comment: Another idea would be to replace 5 to smaller number in all occurrences of `multiplyScalar( 5 )` (https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/canvas_geometry_birds.html#L80)